# How to set systemNavigationBarColor using flutter dynamic color package

Tags: android, flutter, material-ui, material3

[This app is using material 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5ztv.jpg)
[This is google dialer app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaZLu.jpg)

See the google dialer app which is using dynamic color of material ui systemNavigationBarColor is same as the bottom navigation bar, but in my app it's black (not same as bottom navigation bar)

Though I can set it manually but dynamic color feature will be ruined.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.